# Thymeleaf not displaying fragments

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to learn Thymeleaf and when using th:fragment and th:replace or th:insert, nothing is displayed on the page. This is in intellij Idea using the spring boot framework.

What I've tried:

Changing routing on th:insert (ex. th:insert="fragments/test::test">)
Trying different code in the fragment
Changing test.html to include / not include 
"xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org""
Stopping / restarting Apache Tomcat for every single change I make

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SC2Hub</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SC2Hub</name>
    <description>SC2Hub</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:insert="test::test"></div>
        <div th:replace="test::test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.html:

```
<div th:fragment="test">
  <h1>Hello from the fragment!</h1>
</div>
```

File structure:

```
project

--src

----resources

------static

--------index.html

------templates

--------fragments

----------test.html
```

Comment: I would say that `index.html` is not a static resource (like an image, or a CSS library) but is something which belongs in `/resources` - something which should not be _directly_ accessible to the browser. If you move `index.html` into `/resources` then your fragments are in a sub-directory of `/resources`, relative to where your template is now located: `<div th:replace="fragments/test::test"></div>`.

Comment: Also, you have 2 `/resources` directories - so I think the lower one on your list should be renamed to `/templates`.

Comment: @andrewJames I just tried that and had the same problem. Everything was blank. Thank you for your response. Also yes, it is named templates but I mistyped it in the question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Understood, thank you. In that case, something else is going on, because I can use your directory structure and your files without any problems: the fragment is displayed (twice). I cannot recreate the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given code I see 2 issues. The first is that your index.html is not inside the templates folder, all files used by thymeleaf should be inside this folder unless you've overriden the default value of where thymeleaf looks for files.

After that as mentioned by @andrewJames fragment calls should be relative to the thymeleaf source folder (by default `src/main/resources/templates`) and in your case that would be `<div th:replace="fragments/test::test"></div>`

Comment: The 2 issues you mention were already covered by clarifications in the question's comments.

Comment: Should update question code accordingly than. As it's now you'r asking people to debug an issue on old code

Comment: Agreed. Perhaps the OP can double-check the suggested fixes, also, just to be sure.

Comment: This was it. I moved index to templates and it worked. @andrewJames said to put it in resources which did not work. When I put it in templates it started functioning properly. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: I said to put it in resources and the rename resources to templates.